# Components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I know there are lots of questions about this subject and I have looked at a bunch of them.  But from everything I read my schema looks correct.  But I still get this error when I try to validate the schema:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'addr:coordinatesElement'. It was detected that 'addr:coordinatesElement' is in namespace 'urn:ajga.address:1.0', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///C:/Users/tmcginnis/Workspaces/MyEclipse%202015%20CI/nanda-schema-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/src/main/resources/schema/AddressSchema_1_0.xsd'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'addr:coordinatesElement' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///C:/Users/tmcginnis/Workspaces/MyEclipse%202015%20CI/nanda-schema-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/src/main/resources/schema/AddressSchema_1_0.xsd'.

Here is the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="urn:ajga:address:1.0"
    xmlns:tns="urn:ajga.address:1.0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    version="1.0">
    <xsd:element name="address">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="addressType" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="addressLine1" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="addressLine2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="pobox" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="zip" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="countyCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="country" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="fips" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="coordinates" type="tns:coordinatesElement" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="coordinatesElement">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="longitude" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="lattitude" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3):

The namespace prefix `tns` should be set to the same URI as the `targetNameSpace` attribute. 
notice the difference between the following URI:

```
targetNamespace="urn:ajga:address:1.0" 
                         ^ 
      xmlns:tns="urn:ajga.address:1.0"
                         ^
```